# Amazon RDS Connection Denied via additional user

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-rds

I just created a new database and user grant all privileges on that user. I don't know what's happening I can't connect by using that user always "Access Denied". But I change to RDS master user it's working fine. Could any one explain?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the RDS DB or which command?.

Comment: I am trying to access from SSH and also from PHP code via user I just created in RDS. It works fine I use RDS master user.

Comment: I though it might cause from Global privileges with grant option while creating new account.

Comment: You can't `GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES` in RDS, because even the master user doesn't have the `SUPER` privilege (which is part of "all" privileges).  Are you oversimplifying what you did, in this question, or is there a possibility that an error was disregarded? By what process did you create the new user? Also, `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'newuser';` may be helpful.